# Windows Service Bus Connection string for IIS

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I use in house windows service bus setup on my VM and configure 1 service bus and 2 queue into the same
When I am try to access them from Visual studio its work fine
I used SAS authentication , following is my connection string

Endpoint=sb://amo-test-01/ServiceBusBDemo;StsEndpoint=https://amo-test-01:9355/ServiceBusBDemo;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355;

But when I host this into the IIS on same VM its through as following error 
"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:a38586c2-c795-4472-b393-33e78db1d271_Gamo-test-01,TimeStamp:3/13/2018 6:08:31 AM ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 40100: Unauthorized.TrackingId:a38586c2-c795-4472-b393-33e78db1d271_Gamo-test-01,TimeStamp:3/13/2018 6:08:31 AM

Comment: not sure if this is a new project or not, but be aware that WSSB is out of support.

Comment: @SeanFeldman , Its old project I need to setup on VM , WSSB is out of support but how we configure it on IIS